# Href en javascript

Tags: javascript, url

A ver si me explico ...

Tengo una vista en la que tengo un href que viene dada por una función javascript que tengo en un fichero .js.

El caso es que el link se genera perfectamente, simplemente la función javascript tiene un

`window.location.href = "link que se genera"`

Cuando le haces click con el botón izquierdo el link se abre en la misma ventana y pestaña, pero si le das al botón derecho -> abrir en una nueva pestaña esto es lo que sucede:

> about:blank

en principio no tengo ningún prevent ni nada por lo que no debería estar interfiriendo con los clicks ni yo los gestiono de ninguna forma ya que se genera una url normal y corriente.

¿Alguna idea?

El código es más o menos este

En la vista:

```
<a rel="nofollow"  href="javascript:link.Generator.go('<?echo$pageId?>')" class="automatic"></a>
```

Y el js:

```
go: function(id){
    window.location.href = baseUrl+'/id/'+id;
}
```

Comment: Eso es porque `window.location.href` cambia la URL de la ventana actual, si la abres en otra ventana, no ejecuta esa función.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Existe la posibilidad de que ejecutes en tu Javascript la siguiente orden?

```
document.getElementById('enlace').setAttribute('href', baseUrl+'/id/'+id);
```

Donde tu enlace sería el siguiente:

```
<a rel="nofollow" id="enlace" href="#" class="automatic">Enlace</a>
```

Esto asignará el atributo `href` sin tener que hacer click en el enlace, para que se asigne el `href`.

Comment: @cnbandicoot como es posible abrir dicha funcion sin tener que hacer click en el href ?

Comment: @JuanPablo ¿Y cuando quieres que se ejecute entonces?

Comment: @cnbandicoot como una funcion (lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla y al hacer click en el link href se despliega la tabla, por lo que tambien quiero que se despliegue por mediante la misma funcion sin tener que hacer click en el link href)

Answer (score 1):

Al tener el generador de `URL` en una función, imagino que esto es algo que necesitas en varios elementos, no solo en uno. Una idea es que al inicio de tu aplicación recorras todos los elementos que necesitan el generador de `URL` y les asignes la propiedad `href` con la `URL` generada. Por ejemplo, si el código de tus elementos `a` es el siguiente:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="#" data-href="<?echo $pageId?>" class="automatic"></a>
```

Podrías recorrerlos todos y generar la `URL` de los mismos tomando en cuenta el valor de `data-href`. Algo similar al siguiente snippet:

```js
const baseUrl = "http://fakedomain.com";
const link = {
  Generator: {
    go: (id) => `${baseUrl}/id/${id}`
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll('.automatic').forEach(a => (a.href = link.Generator.go(a.dataset.href)));
```

```html
<a rel="nofollow" href="#" data-href="200" class="automatic">Link 200</a><br>

<a rel="nofollow"  href="#" data-href="300" class="automatic">Link 300</a><br>

<a rel="nofollow"  href="#" data-href="400" class="automatic">Link 400</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código html seria este

```
<a rel="nofollow"  oncontextmenu="link.Generator.go2('<?echo$pageId?>')" onclick="link.Generator.go('<?echo$pageId?>')"   class="automatic"></a>
```

Y estas serian las funciones:

```
go: function(id){
    window.open(baseUrl+'/id/'+id);
}

go2: function(id){
    window.locationf=baseUrl+'/id/'+id;
}
```

*oncontextmenu* lo que hace es llamar la función cuando detecta el evento de dar click derecho.

Comment: Esto siempre va a hacer que se abra en una nueva ventana. No sé si el que pregunta, querrá eso.

Comment: con window.open() me abrirá el link en una nueva pestaña cuando hago click con el botón izquiero pero yo no quiero eso, con el izquiero debe abrirse en la misma ventana y cuando haga click con el derecho y use la opción abrir en nueva ventana o pestaña que me lleve al sitio, lo que pasa es que no lleva al sitio, deja el about:blank

Comment: Listo, te entiendo. Lo que debes de hacer es ejecutar dos funciones en el mismo botón. Una para el izquierdo y otra para el derecho. Editaré mi respuesta.